# Making a list of empty lists from a character vector, is there a better way?

Tags: r

I have written a loop for creating a list of empty lists from a character vector. The output list contains one empty list for each item in the character vector with that character string as its name. This is a reproducible example of what I have written:

```
charVect <- rownames(mtcars)

listOfLists <- list()

for ( i in seq_along(charVect)){
  charVect[i]
  listOfLists[[charVect[i]]] <- list()

}
```

I it seems a few too many lines of code for what it does and I can't find a similar question here or a function that will achieve the same goal on my googlings.

Is this the best way? Are there any functions or methods I could use instead to reduce the lines of code here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
setNames(lapply(vector("list", nrow(mtcars)), function(x) list()), rownames(mtcars))
```

Comment: This does not give me the same output as my example. It produces a list of character vectors instead of a list of named empty lists.

Comment: I see, the list elements do not have a class and when I add an item they become list.

Comment: test <- setNames(vector("list", nrow(mtcars)), rownames(mtcars))
class(test$`Mazda RX4`)
test1 <- "testtest"
test$`Mazda RX4`$test <- test1
class(test$`Mazda RX4`)